# How can I change the text of my low and critical battery notifications on my Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: power, notifications

Windows 10 laptops' low and critical battery notifications are not as "forceful" (?) as how it was in previous versions.  This is just plain weird because Windows is alerting you to take action, but the notifications are to "calm".

This is what my low battery notification looks like:

> ### Your battery is running low (10%).
>
> You might want to plug in your PC.

And for the critical battery notification:

> ### Your battery is very low (7%).
>
> Plug in your PC now.

The problem is, that the warnings are too weak.  Back in the old days, the messages were rather forceful and it alerted me to plug in my PC.

For example, here is what Windows 7's low battery notification looked like:

> ### 27 min (10%) remaining
>
> Your battery is low (10%).  If you need to continue using your computer, either plug in your computer, or shut it down and change the battery.

And for the critical battery notification (much more dramatic than the low battery one):

> ### *Critical Battery Warning: You are now running in reserve power mode*
>
> *Your battery is very low (7%), please plug it in immediately.  If you don't, your computer will soon automatically hibernate.*

But on Windows 10, the warnings are not very strict and I often end up simply ignoring them until the computer soon dies out and it is too late.

How can I modify the text?  Or can I actually **do** it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **NOT** do this in native Windows. If there was a way, it would be via a registry hack, but that's just not possible.

The only thing you CAN change is the name of the power profiles and on what percentage the notifications should be shown.

In order to be reminded better/faster, you could write some script that is triggered via a scheduled task and that warns you.

Alternatively you could buy/download a third party app that forces some notification prompts like eg. [this app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/battery-alarm-free/9n1v03mzcz86?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#). 
(There used to be battery warning apps via the manufacturer of the devices, but I'm not sure whether that's still a thing.)